# swift forward geolocating and accessing the placemark longitude and longitude

Tags: swift, geocoding

I used forward geocoding to get a 2d coordinate of my event. Now im trying to get the longitude and latitude of the event address. I have managed to create a placemark containing coordinates, but i dont know how change it from coordinate to the longitude or latitude

any ideas?

```
if let objects = objects {
    for object in objects {

        self.geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        //get address from object
        let COAddress = object.objectForKey("Address")as! String
        let COCity = object.objectForKey("City")as! String
        let COState = object.objectForKey("State")as! String
        let COZipCode = object.objectForKey("ZipCode")as! String
        let combinedAddress = "\(COAddress) \(COCity) \(COState) \(COZipCode)" //all parts of address
        print(combinedAddress)

        //make address a location

        self.geocoder.geocodeAddressString(combinedAddress, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if(error != nil)
            {

                print("Error", error)
            }

            else if let placemark = placemarks?[0]
            {

                let placemark:CLPlacemark = placemarks![0]
                var coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
                print("i got here", coordinates)

            }
        })

       let userLatitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
       let userLongitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
       let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: userLatitude!, longitude: userLongitude!)

       // event location - THE ERROR IS BELOW
       let eventLatitude = placemarks.location?.cordinate.latitude
       let eventLongitude = placemarks.location?.coordinate.longitude
       let eventLocation = CLLocation(latitude: eventLatitude!, longitude: eventLongitude!)

       //Measuring my distance to my buddy's (in km)

       let distance = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(eventLocation) / 1000

         //Display the result in km
         print("The distance to event is ", distance)

         if (distance < 100) {

             print("yay")
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> // event location - THE ERROR IS BELOW
>        let eventLatitude = placemarks.location?.cordinate.latitude
>        let eventLongitude = placemarks.location?.coordinate.longitude
>        let eventLocation = CLLocation(latitude: eventLatitude!, longitude: eventLongitude!)
> ```

I believe you need to access `placemarks.first.location` or `placemarks[0].location`